# Follow the tutorials still ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll error

Tags: php

I have followed the tutorials and installed ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll.

When I check my php.ini in C: \ Program Files (x86) \ PHP \ v5.6 \ I have:

```
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll"
```

when I open php info there is no ..

I do not understand.

In my other i have  7.3 php and that installation Went well.

Answer (score -1):

Then you should use `ioncube_loader_win_7.3.dll` not `ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll`

Here is official [download page](https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php)

> Installing with the Loader Wizard (recommended)

Comment: im trying to install 7.2 loader, my code want manage 7.3. but still i cant se 7.2 zend loader

Comment: sorry that i dont use ioncube myself, and i dont use windows OS, i cant help more than this

Comment: i follow loader-wizard and it say that i shoud use 7.2, i move it to the folder ext, i add it ot the right php.ini.. restart iis. and it not  installed. :(

Comment: may you have multiple php versions installed, your php.exe in windows enviroment may is 7.2 (that used with cmd) and your running php may is different 7.3 for example

Comment: if `ioncube_loader_win_7.3.dll` file exists, Try set manually in `php.ini`, Then **restart the Apache**